# USA interactive map

Tags: jquery, maps

I need USA interactive map for http://pfitr.net/frontend/compliant-reporting.html

In the blue bar there is select drop down. Selecting the state should display that state name at left side, select the corresponding state in the map and then display text corresponding to that state at the right side of the map.

I used the script at http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/  with raphael.js & scale.raphael.js

Javascript / jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#map').usmap({
    'click' : function(event, data) {
      $('#alert')
        .text(data.name)
        .stop();

    }
  });
});

var paper = new ScaleRaphael("#map", 500, 310);
function resizePaper(){
  var win = $(this);
  paper.changeSize(win.width(), win.height(), true, false);
}
resizePaper();
$(window).resize(resizePaper);
```

Html

```
<div class="blue-bar">
    <div class="sub-title-left" >
          <h1 class="us-state" id="alert">missouri</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="report-content2">
      <div class="usa-map"><div id="map" style="width: 510px; height: 310px;">   
      </div>  </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
</div>
```

But scaling is not working when the window is resized. It is responsive site.

Any help ?

Comment: Yet to try the script. The current website layout is responsive too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably better ways but maybe something like this?

```
$('#map').usmap({
   // The click action
   click: function(event, data) {
      SelectState(data.Name, [SOMECOLOR]);
   }
});


$([SelectYourDropDown]).change(function(){

    var stateAbb = //set the abbreviation for the state

    $('#map').usmap('trigger', stateAbb, 'click');
});

function SelectState(state, color)
{
   ResetStates();

   $('#map').usmap({
      state: {fill : color}
   });
}

function ResetStates()
{
  $('#map').usmap({
     stateStyles: {fill: 'blue'}
  });

}
```

Comment: I should probably add a disclaimer. I haven't used this plug-in before nor have I tested this example.